# How to fix "TypeError: RenderUtil is undefined"

Tags: civivolunteer

I get the following JavaScript error in my console when I try to Define Volunteer Opportunities for a project in CiviVolunteer:

> TypeError: RenderUtil is undefined

I don't get this error on my local install. The only difference I can see is that renderutils.js is loaded as the last script on my live site (which gives the error) and is loaded not as last on my local site (which works correctly).

Also see the following image:

[image]

Comment: So, I kind of solved it myself. The renderutils.js file was in a folder called "_utils". It seems that this caused it to be loaded as last. When I renamed it to "autils" the file was loaded earlier. This causes it to work. However, this doesn't sound like the right solution. I will mark this as answer when nobody comes up with a better solution.